# Change color of cube three js

Tags: three.js

I am using BoxHelper to create wireframe for cube and to solve diagonal issue, but only problem I am facing is I can't apply color to cube. As BoxHelper uses Line I cant use material, and also if I add cube to scene it is overriding boxhelper lines and I cant see lines. Is there any possible solution to appear lines as well as color to cube.

Answer (score 0):

check the both fiddle link.. you will get some idea..

http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/s2tP2/..

```
 var wireMesh = new THREE.BoxHelper(mesh);
 wireMesh.material.color = new THREE.Color(0x0000ff);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/s2tP2/1/

```
var wireMesh = new THREE.BoxHelper(mesh);
wireMesh.material.color.set(0x0000ff);
```